# Range of WiFi network Android API

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is there an API to check if we are in the range of a WiFI Network or not? Can we do the same using the RSSI strength of the network.

Comment: Scan and check that your wifi's SSID matches with any of the scanned SSID. If matches then it is in your range otherwise not.